# Is there a way to access clipboard contents?

Tags: automated-tests, clipboard, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am testing a page that has an embed modal with a textbox with an embed code and a "Copy" button that should copy the contents of the textbox onto the clipboard so a user can paste it elsewhere. Is there a way to test clicking the "Copy" button and verifying that the clipboard contents match the contents of the textbox? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try simulating a "CTRL+V" key press somewhere to assert that the content pasted is ok ?

Comment: No, I don't have anywhere on the page to paste it other than that single textbox, which seems like an odd test. Plus I don't think CTRL+V works in testcafe right now? https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2466

Answer (score 3):

TestCafe cannot automate a browser's built-in behavior, including the Copy & Paste functionality. It is expected that this functionality works correctly as it is tested by browser developers.

You can try to check that your script/button executes the copy command in the following way:

```
const overwriteCopyCommand = ClientFunction(() => {
    document.execCommand = command => window.lastExecutedCommand = command;
});

const getLastExecutedCommand = ClientFunction(() => window.lastExecutedCommand);

await overwriteCopyCommand();
await t
    .click('.copy-url-button')
    .expect(getLastExecutedCommand()).eql('copy');
```

Unfortunately, according to JavaScript restrictions, I don't see a way how to check the copied text.

See additional workarounds in these threads:

[Support 'ctrl+c' and 'ctrl+v' key combinations for copying/pasting selected text](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2466)

[Allow to use HTML5 Clipboard API in tests](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2668)